# WordPress plugin pagenavi, I can't see more then 2 pages, even with 100+ posts

Tags: php, wordpress, html, plugins

That's how it's looks with 20 posts, and only four posts shows.

[image]

With this, I have 20 posts in this category, I'm showing on the single page only four of them, so i should get 5 pages of navi page plagin, but I get only two of them, and it's doesn't metter how many posts I have.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: strategy
 */
get_header(); ?>
  <div class="template">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="breadcrumb">
          <?php if (function_exists('bcn_display')) {
            bcn_display();
          } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="page_title">
          <h1><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="articles_page__wrapper">
          <?php
          $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 0;
          global $post;
          $args = array(
              'numberposts' => 20,
              'category' => 3,
              'orderby' => 'date',
              'order' => 'DESC',
              'include' => array(),
              'exclude' => array(),
              'meta_key' => '',
              'meta_value' => '',
              'post_type' => 'post',
              'paged' => $paged,
          );
          $myposts = get_posts($args);
          foreach ($myposts as $post) {
            setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="img">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                  <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('small'); ?>" 
  alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="group">
                <div class="title">
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="description">
                  <p><?php echo excerpt(40); ?></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          <?php }
          wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
        <article>
          <?php
          $id = 8;
          $post = get_post($id);
          echo $content = $post->post_content;
          ?>
        </article>
    <?php if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) wp_pagenavi(); ?>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the wp_pagenavi use like this:

```
<?php if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $myposts ) ); ?>
```